# TYPO3 plugin without caching

Tags: caching, typo3, fluid, extbase

I've written an extension with Extbase/Fluid and this extension has a plugin:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyVendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi1',
    array(
        'MyController' => 'list'
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'MyController' => 'list'
    )
);
```

But when creating a link

```
<f:link.action arguments="{foo: 'bar'}">...</f:link.action>
```

the resulting url has a cHash parameter:

```
http://localhost/mypage/?tx_myext_pi1[foo]=bar&cHash=d1768a40d9370f7a8d327043da156a05
```

Why? I defined this plugin as "do not cache" so there should be no cHash parameter.

TYPO3 version is 7.6.12.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why deactivate caching in plugin (not recommended for performance reasons) and why get rid of cHash? If you state the goal in the question, it might be possible to give better answers.

Comment: I wanted to get rid of the cHash. I understand now, why it is needed and how to get rid of it (use site config to make the url speaking). I know the disadvantages of uncached plugins, but often, they are needed and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cHash` parameter is not used to cache your content, but to cache the arguments in the url, so it has nothing to do with the action itself being cached or not.

If your action is cached and you see no changes when you change the template or the code, than may be you changed the cache settings of the action and the localconf is still cached. In that case you have to clear the system cache in the install tool or uninstall and install your extension.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the cHash parameter you can use the `f:link` ViewHelper Argument `noCacheHash`:

```
<f:link.action arguments="{foo: 'bar'}" noCacheHash="true">...</f:link.action>
```

The cHash is not used only for you plugin. Also for the rest of your page (layout, etc) so TYPO3 set always an cHash if you have an argument.

If you use RealURL, the cHash disapear if you have mapped all arguments in the url.

Comment: The problem is not only the cHash, if do not want the plugin contents to be cached. I know "noCacheHash" but I do not want to use it, I want to do it the right way / I want Extbase/Fluid to do it the right way. And I can't use "noCacheHash" for the pagination of my plugin contents (f:widget.paginate), so these links also have the cHash parameter.

Comment: Why should "noCacheHash" to be an "wrong" way? The behaivor is to add always an cHash if an parameter in the url is set. In your pagination template you can also set the "noCacheHash" argument. And of course: If you use an extension to make "nicer urls" you can remove the cHash by mapping all parameters correctly. If you don't have "nice urls" it doesnt matter of one or more paramets, or?

Comment: I looked in the source of the uri builder so I can say: cHash is allways added if "noCacheHash" is not set an an parameter is added to the url. So it doesn't matter if you use non-cacheable actions or not.

Comment: You wrote "If you use an extension to make "nicer urls" you can remove the cHash by mapping all parameters correctly": The cHash parameter is still in use then and the page is cached. You wrote: "If you don't have "nice urls" it doesnt matter of one or more paramets, or?" Of course it matters, the page contents are cached, that has, in some cases, many disadvantages.

Comment: The cHash parameter is allways setted if you have an parameter in your url. The cHash doesn't determine if you plugin is cached oder not. If you use an non-cacheable action and the plugin is cached this is an other problem.

Comment: noCacheHash parameter in link.action has been deprecated and dropped in 11.0. Please see up to date information about caching in TYPO3! https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-91473-DeprecatedFunctionalityRemoved.html

Comment: More info in deprecation Changelog: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Deprecation-88406-SetCacheHashnoCacheHashOptionsInViewHelpersAndUriBuilder.html

Comment: More "in depth information" by Benni Mack (2020) https://b13.com/blog/caching-in-typo3-part-2-cache-variants-of-a-page-with-chash, see also other resources linked in blog article.